# select dentro de un ciclo vuejs

Tags: vue.js

Hola buenas noches estoy haciendo un componente con vuejs en donde tengo un formulario dentro de un ciclo con un select pero tengo el inconveniente que el select como es el mismo me afecta los demás y necesito que el comportamiento de los selects sea independiente, como puedo lograr este comportamiento. De antemano muchas gracias por la ayuda:

```
    <div class="col-md-4 my-2" v-for="producto in productos" :key="producto.id">
    <div>{{producto.nombre}}</div>
    <select class="form-control" v-model="selected">
       <option value="0" selected>pequeño</option>
       <option value="1">mediano</option>
       <option value="2">grande</option>
     </select>
    </div>

    data() {
       return {
          nombre: '',
          arrayProducto: [],
          selected: ''
       }
   },
```

Comment: usa un modelo de datos diferente para cada uno.

Comment: pero es que este select lo tengo por cada uno de los registros que traigo desde una base de datos...

Comment: y puedes guardarlo en varias variables en vez de una. Para más ayuda pon más código.

Comment: El `v-model` puedes usarlo como un componente del item del primer `v-for`, agrega mas código para ver el caso

Comment: Ya edite el codigo...

Comment: v-model no tiene que apuntar a una variable sola.. tiene que apuntar a algo parecido sobre lo que estas siclando.. del estilo producto.selected...

Comment: Ha ok muchas gracias voy a probar...